# can't get keras models or tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset to run on Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, mnist

I have always used Google Colab and Jupyter notebook before, for TensorFlow certification I have to use PyCharm.  So far identical to Colab tf.keras models can't compile, can't load mnist data, and tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset doesn't work in PyCharm.   If anybody has examples of doing these things in PyCharm I would surely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

evidently something was wrong with Cuda in PyCharm, added `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` to run on CPU, fixed my problems